# Get number of available products in a Shopify collection

Tags: shopify

I realise I can use `collection.products_count` to get products count for a collection, but is it possible to get the count of **available** products, e.g. not sold?

Comment: Keep in mind that Liquids loops are limited to 50 iterations.
So you won't really get the number of available products in this collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to iterate over the products and check their availability:

```
{% assign available_products = 0 %}

{% for product in collection.products %}
  {% if product.available %}
    {% assign available_products = available_products | plus: 1 %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{{ available_products }}
```

Comment: in 2022 is it still the case?

Comment: in 2023 is it still the case?